# pyplot - issue with graphic being refreshed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made this code that plots a graph based on the data of some txt files (which keep being updated by another program)

```
k=0

xs=[]
ys=[]


fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
def animate(i):
    a=open("c:/python27/pos/12386.txt","r").read()
    lines=a.split("\n")    #gets the data from each line

    for line in lines:
        if len(line)>1:
            ys.append(int(line[:line.find(".")]))
            xs.append(len(xs)+1)

    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs,ys,linewidth=1.0)

ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate, interval=6000)
plt.show()
```

how ever, after every 6 seconds, he repeats the graphic, which becomes a pattern with a new instance every 6 seconds.

I guess i should run a command inside the loop to clear the graphic before it gets plotted again, or plot every new point one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that lists `xs` and `ys` are always extended with whole text file. What you need to do is to clear them before adding the contents of the text file.

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    a=open("c:/python27/pos/12386.txt","r").read()
    lines=a.split("\n")    #gets the data from each line
    xs=[]
    ys=[]

    for line in lines:
        if len(line)>1:
            ys.append(int(line[:line.find(".")]))
            xs.append(len(xs)+1)

    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs,ys,linewidth=1.0)

ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate, interval=6000)
plt.show()
```

Or, you could only read the new lines and append those (if the updates are only adding lines).